# Through Impyla,How to fetch millions of data row by row?

Tags: python-3.x, impyla

For example,some python package such as *vertica_python* have the function of *iterate()*.
    With this,we can fetch data row by row using
    *for row in cursor.iterated():*
    Which is very useful to process big query with millions of lines.
    Is there any similiar way in package *impyla*?

Answer (score 0):

Found One:

```
 cr.execute('select * from tables')
    for row in cr:
```